# Is there a 'rake routes' for wordpress?

Tags: url-rewriting, redirect, urls, routing

Is there an equivalent to 'rake routes' in php/wordpress that would spit out all the available wordpress url paths available?

Comment: No, there is not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var_dump( $GLOBALS['wp_rewrite'] );
```

this is as close as you'll get.

Anyway, there're plugins like the "MonkeyMan Rewrite Analyzer"  and toschos [T5 Rewrite](https://github.com/toscho/t5-rewrite/) plugins that will allow you other nice things too.